# MVC Frameworks and General Purpose files

Tags: model-view-controller

When using MVC framework, where should I place general purpose classes that aren't necessarily deserving of a model?

Comment: do you mean to say classes like session class, cookie class pertaining to mvc? classes pertaining to your app?

Comment: yes, things like that + other general purpose stuff like login validation classes, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would Say:

If classes are pertaining to app e.g. login validation put it under app/libraries.
If classes are pertaining to MVC e.g. session class put it under /libraries

`/` being your DocumentRoot.

BTW I am writing an MVC for a project of mine. Which is ~90% complete.
It is good to keep the files as segregated as possible (by experience).

Here is the directory structure of Obullo MVC:

[image: Obullo]

Answer (score 1):

Codeigniter which is an MVC framework would have you put them in a `libraries` file. This is outside and independent of the MVC triad.